# how to clean up the previous expect_buf in an expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I've written a expect function to get the output of a command and my code is like below

```
proc do_cmd {cmd id} {
  set spawn_id $id
  send "$cmd\r"
  expect "$cmd\r"
  expect {
    -re "\n(.*)\r\n" {return $expect_out(1,string)}
    default {exit 1}
  }
}
```

If I call the function just once it would works fine and return something I want, but if I call it continually without a break, it would return something unwanted.

```
# test case 1
set ret [do_cmd $mycmd $spawn_id]
puts "$mycmd returns $ret"  # the return value is ok

# test case 2
set ret [do_cmd $mycmd $spawn_id]
set ret [do_cmd $mycmd $spawn_id]
puts "$mycmd returns $ret"  # the return value is not something I want
```

I use the 'exp_internal 1' to debug it and found that the expect_out in the second called command still holds the previous output info and caused the matched problem, so how can I clean up the expect_out buffer(I tried to set it an empty string but it doesn't work,) or is there anything else I can do to avoid this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need `-re "\n(.*)\r\n"` to match for regular expression ?  because you are using `expect_out(1,string)`

Comment: Oops, my mistake, thank you for remind me that

Answer (score 12):

Don Libes's suggestion for your scenario is as follows,

> Sometimes it is even useful to say:
>
> `expect *`
>
> Here the * matches anything. This is like saying, "I don't care what's
>   in the input buffer. Throw it away." This pattern always matches, even
>   if nothing is there. Remember that * matches anything, and the empty
>   string is anything! As a corollary of this behavior, this command
>   always returns immediately. It never waits for new data to arrive. It
>   does not have to since it matches everything.

Reference : [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

In this case, after your required match, better try to save the match to some variable then simply add the code `expect *` at the last. This will empty the buffer. Your code can altered as below.

```
proc do_cmd {cmd id} {
  set spawn_id $id
  send "$cmd\r"
  #Looks like you are looking for a particular command to arrive
  expect "$cmd\r"
  #Then you have one more expect here which is you want to get it
  expect {
    #Saving the value sub match to the variable 'result'
    -re "\n(.*)\r\n" {set result $expect_out(1,string)}}
    }
  #Causing the buffer to clear and it will return quickly
  expect *
  return $result
}
```

Apart from this, there is one more way can be unsetting the `expect_out(buffer)` content itself which will remove the 'buffer' index from  `expect_out` array which can be depicted as

```
unset expect_out(buffer)
```

When the next match happens, `expect_out` array will be updated the index 'buffer' and we can have the fresh `expect_out(buffer)` value. Replace the `expect *` with the above code if you prefer to use this way.

This is quite a workaround kind of stuff to get what we want actually. You can go ahead with any approach. Choice is yours. :)

Comment: I've determined empirically that unsetting the expect_out(buffer) is much more consistent than "expect *". This post was of great help for me. Stackoverflow is indispensable like always.